# Downloading keystore from MIT App inventor and using it with phonegap

Tags: cordova, app-inventor, android-keystore

I have made a couple of apps with MIT app inventor an now i wanted to try at make the same apps in HTML, javascript and CSS using phonegap.

I have succesfully created the app. But now I need to use the keystore that was created and autosigned in app inventor but with phonegap build instead.

I can download the keystore file, but what i my title, Alias, Keypasword, and certifikat password. I is not metioned on the App inventor homepage and I am shure that I have not set it up.

Answer (score 0):

see also here https://groups.google.com/d/msg/apptomarket/Aj5sumtcW4s/CfdlsRXrVlUJ
the defaults are
password=**android**
alias=**androidKey**